# Ruby: String Ranges in a Pig Latin translator

Tags: ruby, string, rspec, range

I am currently doing Test First's rspec tutorial and have a question pertaining to the Pig_Latin problem.

Specifically I want to know about string ranges. Here is a section of my code:

```
if phonemes.include?(word[0]) && phonemes.include?(word[1]) && phonemes.include?(word[2])
 <do something>
end
```

Instead of the above I tried:

```
if phonemes.include?(word[0..2]) # i added that character to the list of phonemes 
  <do something>                 # e.g. if the word is school i added "sch" to 
end                              # the array called phonemes
```

However it does not work even though `"sch"` is in `phonemes` and `word[0..2] == "sch"`

My question is why can I not use string ranges to manipulate the result. (i will post my full code at the bottom in case this is unclear)

Code (work in progress):

```
def translate(string)
array = string.split(" ")
alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
phonemes = alphabet - vowels
phonemes << ["qu", "sch", "thr"]
result = []
array.each do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
        result << (word + "ay")
    elsif phonemes.include?(word[0..1])
        result << "do something"
    elsif phonemes.include?(word[0]) && phonemes.include?(word[1]) && phonemes.include?(word[2])
        result << (word[3..-1] + (word[0..2] + "ay"))
    elsif phonemes.include?(word[0]) && phonemes.include?(word[1])
        result << (word[2..-1] + (word[0..1] + "ay"))
    elsif phonemes.include?(word[0..1])
        result << "do something else"
    elsif phonemes.include?(word[0])
        result << (word[1..-1] + (word[0]+ "ay"))
    end
end
return result.join(" ")
end
```

As always tips to make the code more efficient would be appreciated (but the most important thing for me is to understand why string ranges aren't working).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `phonemes << ["qu", "sch", "thr"]` is adding that array as the last element of `phonemes`, which is why the `include?` is failing.  The `<<` operator is designed to add individual elements to the array.  If you want to add all the elements in that array to `phonemes` you can use the `+=` operator, instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your main question, but you asked for tips to improve your code.  I suggest you consider using a case statement where you have your long if-else.  It makes it more readable and reduces duplication.  Something like this:

```
result << case
  when vowels.include?(word[0])
    word + "ay"
  when phonemes.include?(word[0..1])
    "do something"
  when phonemes.include?(word[0]) && phonemes.include?(word[1])
    if phonemes.include?(word[2])
      word[3..-1] + word[0..2] + "ay"
    else
      word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + "ay"
    end
  when phonemes.include?(word[0..1])
    "do something else"
  when phonemes.include?(word[0])
    word[1..-1] + word[0]+ "ay"
  else
    "do something else or raise an error if you reach this point."
end
```

I did not look at your code closely, but I did notice that you have `phonemes.include?(word[0..1])` twice, so the second one will never be executed.

Comment: haha yea I saw that. I've been rewriting it so much and saving the older copies that I've been getting confused. I just finished the problem (haven't really looked at its efficiency yet because I just finished) but I cleaned that stuff out. Thanks a lot for the reply I will look into those when statements. For clarification whats the difference between `when` and `if` and also what is `result << case`. more specifically what is `case`

Comment: @Sai `when` is a keyword used with the `case` statement.  `case` returns a value, depending on which `when` applies.  Here `case` returns a value that is to be appended to `result`, as you did in your code.  Check the docs for case.